# Generic type for protobuf message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am working with protobuf protocol messages combined with ZeroMq. All my ZMQ message are multipart with the following structure:

- Part 1: protobuf message name (got from descriptor)
- Part 2: Serialized string

In my server class, I want to have a function that that can create the ZMQ message from any protobuf message. How should the definition of the function look like?

Here is what I currently have

```cpp
class ZMQ_server
{
public:
    ZMQ_server(zmq::context_t* context, int port=5555);
    ~ZMQ_server();
    bool stop;
    int run_server();


private:
    zmq::context_t* context;
    zmq::socket_t socket;
    int receive_message(std::string* msg_name, std::string* msg_content);

    // process_message parses the type of protobuf message received and calls dedicated methods for each of them (not shown here)
    int process_message(const std::string* req_msg_name, const std::string* req_msg_content, const google::protobuf::Message* msg); // Desired implementation
    int process_message(const std::string* req_msg_name, const std::string* req_msg_content, std::string* rep_msg_name, std::string* rep_msg_content); // Current implementation


    int send_message(const std::string* msg_name, const std::string* msg_content); // Current implementation
    int send_message(const google::protobuf::Message* msg); // Desired implementation
};
```

The source code for the `run_server` function looks like:

```cpp
int ZMQ_server::run_server()
{
    std::cout << "Starting server \n";
    std::string req_msg_name, req_msg_content, rep_msg_name, rep_msg_content;
    while (!stop) {

        int rc;
        // Receive message
        rc = receive_message(&req_msg_name, &req_msg_content);

        // Process message
        rc = process_message(&req_msg_name, &req_msg_content, &rep_msg_name, &rep_msg_content);
        
        // Send reply
        rc = send_message(&rep_msg_name, &rep_msg_content);
    }
    std::cout << "Stopping server \n";

    return rc;
}
```

Since I cannot instantiate a `google::protobuf::Message` object (abstract class), what can I pass to the `process_message` function to retrieve the response protobuf message?

Can I make use of templates for instance (I have never done that, I am not proficient in C++)?

Comment: Side note : IMO you loose a lot when you make generic interfaces with `do_something(string)` kind of interfaces. Create specific methods on your service API with specific request and response messages. That way you'll end up with a well specified API (hopefully correctly versioned according to the proto guidelines too) that is much easier to use for your clients. Yes it might be a bit more typing now but it will safe a lot of problems later.

Comment: Thanks @PepijnKramer for the advice. I assume that I still need this `receive_message` function to receive all kind of requests. Would you then dispatch the messages to dedicated methods from the same function? For now my `process_message` function checks the type of message and then calls a dedicated method. The question boils downs to: where do you parse your protobuf messages?

Comment: In order to know how to deserialize, you need to know (a) what exact kinds (types, classes) of things can be serialized and (b) how to tell these kinds apart by looking at the serialized string. Then you make a switch statement or an if-else chain or a map or whatever else you fancy to dispatch on a serialized string and select a piece of code that can work with the corresponding type.

Comment: (cont) If that's what you already do, perfect, you are doing well. The only question that remains is how to dispatch in a nice idiomatic manner. I would try using a `map<string, function<MsgBase*(string)>>` (or better use a smart pointer as needed).

Comment: Have you read this documentation yet? https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/. My advice write a static C++ library with all your functionality, unit test it and then implement the service using that library. You have to get properties of your request, translate them in to arguments on function calls on your libary and the other way around you need to translate return values (and errors) into responses.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes I had a look at it. However I do not use gRPC, using ZMQ is a constraint from my project. Am I right that they are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Sorry forgot about the ZMQ part, my apologies for the inconvenience (I only have experience with gRPC as transport layer at the moment). That makes my reply not directly applicable. But you should still be able to use protobuf's generated serialization/deserialization code. Which is described here : https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/cpptutorial/. The translation from messages to function calls and back should still be usable.

Comment: How does this differ from [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794963/c-idiomatic-way-of-dispatching-protobuff-messages)?

Comment: @jpa My question yesterday is about the idiomatic way of dispatching. It is also a more generic question, less application specific. This question was more about the architecture of the server, Your answer from yesterday could be applied here as well I guess