# C++: Idiomatic way of dispatching protobuff messages

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a C++ server based on ZeroMQ and Protobuf.

I am looking for an idiomatic way of deserializing and dispatching the messages. In Python I would use a dictionary for this associating a function to each name of protobuf message.

What I currently have is:

```
if (*req_msg_name == "SayHelloReq")
{
    SPDLOG_LOGGER_DEBUG(logger, "Received SayHelloReqrequest");
    axi_ethernet::SayHelloReq msg_req;
    axi_ethernet::SayHelloRep msg_rep;
    msg_req.ParseFromString(*req_msg_content);
    say_hello_function(&msg_req, &msg_rep);
    msg_rep.SerializeToString(rep_msg_content);
    *rep_msg_name = msg_rep.GetDescriptor()->name();
    msg_rep.SerializeToString(rep_msg_content);
}

else if (*req_msg_name == "ReadFileReq")
{
    SPDLOG_LOGGER_DEBUG(logger, "Received ReadFileReq request");
    axi_ethernet::ReadFileReq msg_req;
    axi_ethernet::ReadFileRep msg_rep;
    msg_req.ParseFromString(*req_msg_content);
    read_file_function(&msg_req, &msg_rep);
    msg_rep.SerializeToString(rep_msg_content);
    *rep_msg_name = msg_rep.GetDescriptor()->name();
    msg_rep.SerializeToString(rep_msg_content);
}
```

This `if/else` statement is quite long and a lot of lines in this code are repeated.
The action performed in each block are:

- Create corresponding protobuf messages
- Deserializes the incoming message
- Call a function that takes the request and reply messages as argument
- Serializes the Reply message into a string
- Get the message name into a string (to add to the ZMQ message).

I am trying to minimize the overhead in adding new messages.

I was thinking of creating a map like `std::map<string, std::tuple<msg_req_type, msg_rep_type, ptr_processing_function>` with the string being the `*req_msg_name` and function the processing function that needs to be called. But how I should define my function definition since the argument type of each function is different (but all inherited from a `protobuf::Message`).

If I manage to use a map I could potentially get rid of the `if/else` statement.

Adding support to new messages would just consist in adding a new item to the map.

My question is then: How to define the tuple and the function pointer so that it can accept different types of protobuf messages.

I tried this but it does not work

```
using pfunc =  void(*)(google::protobuf::Message* req_msg, google::protobuf::Message* rep_msg);
std::map<std::string, pfunc> map;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class interface, with template handling the common case of a function with the protobuf messages as arguments:

```
class MessageHandler
{
public:
    virtual void handle_message(std::string *req_msg_content,
             std::string *rep_msg_content, std::string *rep_msg_name) = 0;
};

template <typename ReqType, typename RepType>
class GenericMessageHandler: public MessageHandler
{
public:
    GenericMessageHandler(std::function<RepType, ReqType> function):
        m_function(function) {}

    virtual handle_message(std::string *req_msg_content,
             std::string *rep_msg_content, std::string *rep_msg_name)
    {
        ReqType msg_req;
        RepType msg_rep;
        msg_req.ParseFromString(*req_msg_content);
        m_function(&msg_req, &msg_rep);
        msg_rep.SerializeToString(rep_msg_content);
        *rep_msg_name = msg_rep.GetDescriptor()->name();
    }

private:
    std::function<void, ReqType, RepType> m_function;
};
```

The main program would then contain a map from the message name to handler class. A pointer class like `std::unique_ptr` can be used to handle the polymorphism of the types.

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MessageHandler> > handlers;
handlers["SayHelloReq"] = std::make_unique<GenericMessageHandler<
      axi_ethernet::SayHelloReq, axi_ethernet::SayHelloRep> >(say_hello_function);
handlers["ReadFileReq"] = std::make_unique<GenericMessageHandler<
      axi_ethernet::ReadFileReq, axi_ethernet::ReadFileRep> >(read_file_function);

SPDLOG_LOGGER_DEBUG(logger, "Received " + req_msg_name);
handlers.at(req_msg_name)->handle_message(req_msg_content);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jpa! Very helpful and it fulfill my needs! I have your example working (I will post it soon). Now I am struggling because the functions like say_hello_function are actually member function from some other objects. Any help is welcome

Comment: I will soon post more details

Comment: @Thombou So basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class ?